# Performance of adding CSS class & number of children

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance

I need to dynamically apply some styling to elements `.child-1` and `.child-2` by adding CSS classes.

Should I add them once to `#parent` or to each `.child-`? If I add it to `#parent` would existence of `#large-container` affect the performance?

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child-1"></div>
    <div class="child-2"></div>
    <div id="large-container">
       <!-- a bunch of content here - p tags, images... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

(`.child-1` and `.child-2` are absolute positioned elements on top of #large-container)

```
$('#parent').addClass('myClass1 myClass2');
vs
$('.child-1, .child2').addClass('myClass1 myClass2');
```

Same with just CSS:

```
.myClass1 .child-1,
.myClass2 .child-2 {
  color: red;
}
/* vs */
.myClass1.child-1,
.myClass2.child-2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

`myClass1 myClass2` only apply styles to `#child-1` and 2, they don't add any styles to `#large-container`.

Thank you for advice!

Comment: There is no considerable difference, ID selector is fast.

Comment: Wouldn't adding class to #parent cause some kind of a huge repaint because of #large-container?

Comment: in css you define `.myclass1 #child1` so it doesn't matter the extra large container (or does it ?). to optimize the jq cache your jquery object or at least one up in the tree then access from the cache with `·.find` it is believed to be fast

Comment: That's my question :)  Does the presence of #large-container slows down something when I add classes to #parent?

Comment: the short answer is yes.. the presence of #large-container will have some performance cost if you add classes to parent.. i updated my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14786364/766570) to address this specific case in detail

Comment: Can someone make me two test pages so I can show empirically what the difference is? (I'm on the Chrome DevTools team)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although i think my answer is impossible to verify from a profiler (are there any css/html profiling tools out there in terms of rendering the page etc?) I'll state it based on my experience:

```
$('#parent').addClass('myClass1 myClass2');
```

is faster than

```
$('#child-1, #child2').addClass('myClass1 myClass2');
```

simply because you are traversing the dom tree once rather than twice ie 
`$('#child-1, #child2').addClass('myClass1 myClass2');` is the same as

```
$('#child-1).addClass('myClass1 myClass2');
$('#child-1).addClass('myClass1 myClass2');
```

to theoretically prove that last point imagine your html code looked something like this:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child-1"></div>       

    ... lots and lots of html nodes 

    <div id="child-2"></div>

</div>
```

then looking for `#child-1` is a completely separate operation than looking for `#child-2`.. and when it comes to css/html optimisation.. one of the most expensive operations is the DOM tree traversal.

in the case of `$('#parent').addClass('myClass1 myClass2');` you are traversing the DOM tree once (ie finding where `#parent` is then using css cascading to apply to the elements *within* the narrowed down `#parent` DOM subtree

to address the concern that @tMagwell raised about repainting `#large-container` here is another optimized way of applying css:

```
// store the child-1 node in a variable.. ie whenever you 
// refer to it in the future.. you won't have to traverse the entire DOM again
var child1element = $('#child-1');  
$('#child-1).addClass('myClass1 myClass2');
// referring to child1element costs you nothing big, it's already stored in a variable
child1element.siblings().addClass('myClass1 myClass2');
```

this code works of course assuming that there are only *child-1* and *child-2*.. if you got *child-3*, *child-4*.. *child-n* and only want to apply it to *child-n*.. then you can use 
    `child1element.siblings()[n]`  // where n is the index of the child you want to target, since [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) returns an array

hope this helps!

**update:**

to address this specific point you raised in the comments:

*Does the presence of #large-container slows down something when I add classes to #parent?*

the answer is yes. let me give you a scenario where it definitely does:

css:

```
#parent .class1 .class2
{
  font-size:10pt;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child-1"></div>       
    <div id="child-2"></div>
    <div id="large-container">
      <!-- images etc -->
      <p>hello world!<p>
       <!-- many more p tags that has a lot of text and stuff -->
    </div>
</div>
```

so in this example.. the `font-size:10pt` placed under `#parent .class1 .class2` will definitely impact the contents of `#large-container`.. and the operation costs something.. i have no way to quantify how expensive that is (it would depend on the browser rendering engine etc).. but suffice it to say that there is some cost x that is higher than if you didn't just add class1 and class2 to the parent div.